# SqlBulkCopy throwing exception

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to bulk copy data with 100+ columns into a SQL Server database table. The data may contain around 5000 -10,000 records per set. `SqlBulkCopy` is throwing an error:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.

**NOTE**: the data source and my table both have the same column types and lengths. Even though it is throwing the above exception.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18140012/243373

Answer (score 0):

1. Better check once the columns mapping explicitly
2. This error occurs when column length doesn't match

e.g if the input length is varied i.e if input is of type NVARCHAR(MAX) but the target column is of type NVARCHAR(CONSTANT)

Comment: Both the column lengths are the same and are of the same type too, that's what I mentioned in as a NOTE!