# SQL Bulkcopy Error "The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have a console application is ASP.NET/C#. The process copies a number of tables and therefore, I have a generic method to bulk copy. But there was a change in col size on the source and it started throwing the error. I have included `ColumnMappings` code in my method, but still error does not indicate which column is the error coming from. Please provide suggestions.

```
public static void BulkCopyNew(SqlConnection destinationConnection, string destinationTableName, DataTable dataTable, SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping[] columnMappings)
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            destinationConnection.Open();

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 180; //seconds

            WriteToLogs("Bulk copied " + destinationTableName + "; Count: " + dataTable.Rows.Count);

            foreach (var mapping in columnMappings)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping);
            }

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToLogs(ex.Message + "; Error bulk copy Data");

            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        finally
        {
             dataTable.Dispose();
             destinationConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you know what is the _row_ causing the error? You can add an handler for the SqlRowsCopied event and keep track of the copied rows looking at the SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs.RowsCopied value. Then you could try to understand the value causing the error

Comment: I have specified batchsize and capturing count. But it is hard to make our since it might change order. Moreover, my question is about how to find out which column is causing the issue

Comment: Why not just match the column source and target mapping size? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140012/sqlbulkcopy-the-given-value-of-type-string-from-the-data-source-cannot-be-conv

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0);` just why is that necessary?