# How to convert a list to datatable

Tags: c#, json

I have a class which is converting from `JSON` text

This is my code

```
   SearchResult myojb = (SearchResult)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(SearchResult));
```

And the `SearchResult` class is

```
 public class SearchResult
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        public int total_count { get; set; }
        public string search_id { get; set; }
    }
```

And `DAtum` class is

```
public class Datum
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string added_date { get; set; }
        public string media_type { get; set; }
        public Contributor contributor { get; set; }
        public string aspect { get; set; }
        public string image_type { get; set; }
        public bool is_editorial { get; set; }
        public bool is_adult { get; set; }
        public bool is_illustration { get; set; }
        public bool has_model_release { get; set; }
        public bool has_property_release { get; set; }
        public List<string> releases { get; set; }
        public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
        public List<string> keywords { get; set; }
        public Assets assets { get; set; }
        public List<Model> models { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to convert the List `data` of `SearchResult` class into `datatable`.
for conversion I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100872 answer.
But not understand how to call it with List `data`.

Please help stuck with this issue.

Comment: The link you provided is exactly what you need. Can you show the code you have so far and where you have trouble? Hint: Microsoft recommends uppercase for property name

Comment: You have a method that accepts any kind of generic lists like `List<Datum>`. So you just need to pass it as argument and you get the `DataTable`. What's the problem?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sir I did't understand how to call it with `myojb.data ` or what ?

Comment: @Gitz: do you want a `DataTable` which contains only the rows which are in the `List<Datum>` or do you want one which also contains all properties of `SearchResult`? If the former: `DataTable result = ToDataTable(myobj.data)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sir i only want a `Datatable` which contains only the rows which are in `List<Datum`

Comment: ToDataTable(myojb.data);

Comment: @Neel  Hi !! neel i need your help if you have time?

Comment: hey, yeah say what is the matter @Gitz

Comment: @Neel I am able to create the `datatable` now but inside the  `Datum` class some more `list` and I am not able to get this data into `datatable` rows ..

Comment: @Neel Do you able to understand the issue which I am getting ?

Comment: yes i was looking for that but could not reproduce as can i know what exactly "I am not able to get this data" mean i mean what is happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84073/discussion-between-gitz-and-neel).

Comment: hey @Gitz sorry cant use chat during office it is blocked

Comment: hi, have you got the solution?

Comment: @Neel No dear not yet stuck with this issue actually ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i only want a Datatable which contains only the rows which are in
>   `List<Datum>`

Since you already have the method it's simple:

```
DataTable tblDatum = ToDataTable(myobj.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already got the searchresult with data from json.
As per your Stackoverflow link. The code for converting your list to datatable is as follows:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
            return dataTable;
        }
```

Use will be as follows:

```
SearchResult myobj = (SearchResult)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(SearchResult));
            if (myobj.data != null && myobj.data.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable dt = ToDataTable(myobj.data);
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item[dc]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YourList.CreateDataTable("NewNameForYourDataTable");
```

by the way name for your DataTable is optional so you can write this as well :

```
YourList.CreateDataTable();
```